# Counting records for each day where a child record has a certain value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables (see SQL scripts to create tables and data at the end):

Order table with columns

- ID
- Date

OrderItems table with columns

- OrderID
- ItemTypeID

I need to select the count of orders for every day that have at least one item with ItemTypeID=6000 and the count of orders that do not have ItemTypeID=6000 in the order at all.
So far I got this, but I have no clue how to move on:

```
SELECT
    DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, OrderDate)) AS OrderDate,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(Orders.ID)) AS TotalOrders
FROM
    Orders
JOIN
    OrderItems
ON
    Orders.ID = OrderItems.OrderID 
WHERE
    OrderItems.ItemTypeID = 6000
GROUP BY
    DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, OrderDate))
```

Script to create test data:

```
CREATE TABLE OrderItems(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OrderID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ItemTypeID] [int] NOT NULL
)
CREATE TABLE Orders(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OrderDate] [date] NOT NULL
)
GO
INSERT [OrderItems] ([ID], [OrderID], [ItemTypeID]) VALUES (1, 1, 1000)
INSERT [OrderItems] ([ID], [OrderID], [ItemTypeID]) VALUES (2, 1, 6000)
INSERT [OrderItems] ([ID], [OrderID], [ItemTypeID]) VALUES (3, 2, 1000)
INSERT [OrderItems] ([ID], [OrderID], [ItemTypeID]) VALUES (4, 3, 1000)
INSERT [OrderItems] ([ID], [OrderID], [ItemTypeID]) VALUES (5, 3, 1000)
INSERT [OrderItems] ([ID], [OrderID], [ItemTypeID]) VALUES (6, 4, 1000)
INSERT [OrderItems] ([ID], [OrderID], [ItemTypeID]) VALUES (7, 4, 6000)
INSERT [Orders] ([ID], [OrderDate]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2021-12-01' AS Date))
INSERT [Orders] ([ID], [OrderDate]) VALUES (2, CAST(N'2021-12-01' AS Date))
INSERT [Orders] ([ID], [OrderDate]) VALUES (3, CAST(N'2021-12-02' AS Date))
INSERT [Orders] ([ID], [OrderDate]) VALUES (4, CAST(N'2021-12-03' AS Date))
GO
```

The expected results should look like this:

```
OrderDate   OrdersWithItem  OrdersWithoutItem
2021-12-01  1               1
2021-12-02  0               1
2021-12-03  1               0
```

Comment: Please provide your desired results for the provided sample data.

Comment: THINK! OrderDate is defined as DATE. The expression `DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, OrderDate)) ` does nothing useful. Nor is it needed since you can cast a datetime value to date to accomplish the same thing without the complexity and un-readability. And how much effort do you really save type "dd" rather than "day"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Similar to xQbert's answer) I usually use a CROSS APPLY to calculate an intermediate value that I can then use to feed later logic - in this case a flag indicating whether or not an order has the desired item.

Try:

```
SELECT
    O.OrderDate,
    OrdersWithItem = COUNT(CASE WHEN X.HasItem = 1 THEN 1 END),
    OrdersWithoutItem = COUNT(CASE WHEN X.HasItem = 0 THEN 1 END)
FROM Orders O
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT HasItem = CASE WHEN EXISTS(
        SELECT * FROM OrderItems OI WHERE OI.OrderID = O.ID AND OI.ItemTypeID = 6000
        ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
) X
GROUP BY O.OrderDate
ORDER BY O.OrderDate
```

Note the "1" in the "THEN 1" in the above "COUNT(CASE...)" style is arbitrary. It just needs to be distinguishable from the implied "ELSE NULL" case.

Answer (score 3):

You can use logic in an aggregation function like `COUNT`

```
SELECT
  OrderDate
, COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ItemTypeID = 6000 THEN Orders.ID END) AS OrdersWithItem 
, COUNT(DISTINCT Orders.ID) - COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ItemTypeID = 6000 THEN Orders.ID END) AS OrdersWithoutItem
FROM Orders
JOIN OrderItems
  ON Orders.ID = OrderItems.OrderID 
GROUP BY OrderDate
ORDER BY OrderDate
```

| OrderDate | OrdersWithItem | OrdersWithoutItem |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-12-02 | 0 | 1 |
| 2021-12-03 | 1 | 0 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6fea440f17a11f893fc476b98cbbed6c)*

Comment: Neither of these is correct, you should have a total of 4 orders in your example. You need to group first by `Order.Id`. It's also likely to be more efficient than a conditional `DISTINCT` (which the optimizer will not recognize as being sorted). See for example this fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f810a011f9c0a2a91b18058df795f282

Comment: @Charlieface Ok, I misunderstood. Fixed it. Better now?

Comment: Originally I was counting the orders that have a non-6000 for OrdersWithoutItem. While now, it's not counting the items that have a 6000.

Comment: Looks right now, but as I said, it's probably more efficient to group twice, because (given the right indexes) there will be no sort. The optimizer cannot recognize the `CASE` as being in sort order, so will require another sort

Answer (score 2):

TESTED: [DBFiddle.uk Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=19c8b26cafc08a754cb0d0f63cdc3989)

My theory here is we can use an outer apply to get the top 1 row of an order item which has a desired item.  count those, and simply subtract that count from a total count to get those that do not.
We use coalesce to handle the NULL results from the outer apply when an order doesn't have the item in question.

You really need to add to your test data though as you're not hitting enough test cases to know if the solutions will meet all your needs.

```
SELECT O.OrderDate
     , count(Z.hasItem)  OrdersWithItem
     , count(*)-count(Z.HasItem) as OrdersWithoutItems
FROM Orders O
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 1 as hasItem
             FROM OrderItems OI
             WHERE OI.ItemTypeID=6000 
               AND O.ID = OI.OrderID
             ORDER BY OI.ID ) z
GROUP BY O.OrderDate
```

Comment: Renamed hasDate to hasItem, it made more sense...

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different answer:

We first prepare a subquery (called Typ6000) which returns only those orders (OrderID) containing at least one Item with Type=6000. We then check every  order against this (left join) while counting orders for each day.

Consider how the **OrdersWithItem** column is derived:

If an order includes one or more item type 6000 that OrderId will be in the Typ6000, and **Typ6000.OrderID** will be not-NULL when tested in the **count(case when** function. **Typ6000.OrderID is NOT NULL** will be **true** and the **CASE** expression will return the **Order.ID**. COUNT function will then simply count the ID of the orders with item type 6000.

If an order does not include any item type:6000 that **OrderId** will NOT be in the subquery, and the **Typ6000.OrderID** will be **NULL** when tested. **Typ6000.OrderID is NOT NULL** in **CASE WHEN** will then be **false**, the result of the CASE WHEN function will be **NULL**. The COUNT function ignores NULL values, therefore the **OrdersWithItem** column will not count an order with no item type6000.

**OrdersWithoutItem** is derived similarly.

```sql
select 
    O.OrderDate,
    count(case when Typ6000.OrderID is not null then O.ID else NULL end) as OrdersWithItem,
    count(case when Typ6000.OrderID is null then O.ID else NULL end) as OrdersWithoutItem
    
from #Orders O
     
     left join
     (
      select distinct OrderId
      from #OrderItems OI
      where OI.ItemTypeID=6000
     )  Typ6000
     on Typ6000.OrderId=O.ID

group by O.OrderDate
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).